# Is it possible to have a keyCode equal to keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accessibility

I'm creating a more accessible version of jQuery UI slider with number keys assigned to events that move the slider to different positions. I would like the user to be able to use both sets of numbers on a keyboard.

> Example "49" and "97" for the number 1.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
if(event.keyCode == "49")
{
$("#slider_feedback").html(mod3["rc" + clip + "_1"]);
$("#slider_feedback").show();
$(".ui-slider-handle").css("left", "0%");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `if(event.keyCode == "49" || event.keyCode == "97")` ??

Comment: `if(event.keyCode == "49"||event.keyCode == "97") {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't just put both conditions in IF statement but with OR operator:

```
if(event.keyCode == 49 || event.keyCode == 97)
{
$("#slider_feedback").html(mod3["rc" + clip + "_1"]);
$("#slider_feedback").show();
$(".ui-slider-handle").css("left", "0%");
}
```

See a list of Java script OPERATORS and study it a little bit (JavaScript Assignment Operators are directly connected to this question):
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: What does "||" actually mean?

Comment: It means OR, so it actually says if(something OR something else) { do something }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if(event.keyCode == "49")
```

has to be

```
if(event.keyCode == '49' || event.keyCode == '97')
```

OR

```
if(event.which== 49 || event.which== 97)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make an array mapping the keycodes like that:

```
var mapKeys = [
   49: 0,
   97: 0
];
```

And then, I make only ONE script to handle the keypress.

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
   if(mapKeys[e.keyCode] != undefined){
      $(".ui-slider-handle").css("left", mapKeys[e.keyCode] + "%");
   }
});
```